Unable to Activate Hover Effect on Particles in React with @tsparticles/react
I'm trying to incorporate particles into my React project using @tsparticles/react. Everything seems to be working fine except for the hover effect on the particles.
Despite setting up the hover interactivity in the options object, the hover effect doesn't seem to work as expected. I've checked for any potential CSS or styling issues that might be interfering, but couldn't find any. I'm also using the latest versions of @tsparticles/react and tsparticles-slim.
Could someone please guide me on how to properly activate the hover effect on particles in my React project using @tsparticles/react?
Thank you in advance for your help!
Here's a simplified version of my code:
import Particles from "react-tsparticles";
import { loadSlim } from "tsparticles-slim";
import { useCallback, useMemo, useState } from "react";

const ParticlesComponent = (props) => {
  const [animation, setAnimation] = useState(true);

  const options = useMemo(() => ({
    particles: {
      number: {
        value: 140,
        limit: 140,
        density: {
          enable: true,
          value_area: 800,
        },
      },
      color: {
        value: "#fff",
      },
      background: {
        color: "#000",
      },
      fullScreen: {
        enable: true,
        zIndex: -1,
      },
      interactivity: {
        events: {
          onHover: {
            enable: true,
            mode: 'repulse',
            repulse: {
              distance: 200,
              duration: 0.4,
            },
          },
        },
      },
      links: {
        enable: true,
        distance: 200,
      },
      move: {
        enable: true,
        speed: { min: 1, max: 5 },
      },
      opacity: {
        value: { min: 0.3, max: 0.7 },
      },
      size: {
        value: { min: 1, max: 3 },
      },
    },
  }), []);

  const particlesInit = useCallback((engine) => {
    loadSlim(engine);
  }, []);

  const toggleAnimation = () => setAnimation(!animation);

  return (
    <div style= {{ position: "relative" }
}>
  <Particles id={ props.id } init = { particlesInit } options = { options } />
    <button onClick={ toggleAnimation }> Toggle Animation < /button>
      < /div>
  );
};

export default ParticlesComponent;

